# NAT masquerade refuses to work on Link-Local network

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat, networkmanager

I am developing a device, in terms of usage and network connectivity it is similar to a printer with an Ethernet port. This device should also work in p2p scenarios, i.e. when the Ethernet port of the device is connected directly to an Ethernet port of a notebook, in absence of a DHCP server. In this case, both devices obtain a Link-Local address in the `169.254.x.x` address range. So far, so good, this works.

My device has a somewhat complex internal Ethernet topology with multiple different boards that all have their own IP address in a tiny internal network. But none of that concerns the user of the device - the user only sees and talks to one single IP address. This is done using NAT and masquerade. The device has one single entry point with one external IP address and there's port forwarding to serve different boards and functions. This also seems to work well as a concept.

Now here's the problem: NAT masquerade refuses to work with Link-Local IP addresses. It just won't properly rewrite the source address the way I instructed it to on this interface (instead, it just takes the first IP address it finds on *another* Ethernet interface, usually the internal one, which is extremely undesirable). I now think I tracked it down to the so-called `scope` of the address: http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-address.html#tb-tools-ip-addr-scope . This `scope` must be `global`, or else NAT masquerade seems to ignore it. I don't exactly know where this behavior comes from, so I'd like to know more about this.

- How can I coerce NAT masquerade to ignore this unwanted `scope` filtering? I'm using `firewalld` but can also directly use `iptables`. The issue happens on both.
- Alternatively, how can I configure this `scope` to `global` even though I'm using a Link-Local address? I am using Network Manager with `ipv4.method` set to `link-local` on that interface and I need NAT masquerade to work reliably.

Additional information:

It seems like TCP connections that are initiated from outside the device are NATed correctly. The source address of packets sent from the device really is rewritten to the external IP of the device. The problem happens when, from inside the device, a UDP packet is sent or a new TCP socket is established to the user's computer. Then, the source address of these packets is *not* NATed correctly and instead some other address from another interface is inserted.

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: Linux (built with buildroot)

Comment: That might relate, as many mature distributions now treat link-local as global by default. However, I can't help with buildroot.

Comment: @harrymc That is very interesting, can you post a link where you found this information? I cannot find anything about this, neither via search nor via browsing the source code of various widely used projects. So IPv4 Link-Local is now treated as global by default? On which distributions?

Comment: I don't remember - it's something I happened upon some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to work around this issue when using Network Manager. The `link` scope is unfortunately **hardcoded** in Network Manager on the following line of code which automatically selects the scope whenever an IPv4 address is added:

https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/d07383d3f36054ea243a86988383b4113a0e6b6e/src/libnm-platform/nm-linux-platform.c#LL9745C48-L9745C48

Basically the logic is: If the IPv4 address is `127.x.x.x`, then the scope is `RT_SCOPE_HOST`, else if the address is `169.254.x.x`, then the scope is `RT_SCOPE_LINK` and in all other cases, it's `RT_SCOPE_UNIVERSE` (universe is `global`). It forces the scope of the address with no way to configure it.

So I see no other solution than to alter this code before compiling Network Manager. Basically I changed the line linked above to never use the `link` scope and that resolved my NAT issues on link-local addresses because they now have `global` scope.

I'm not fully happy with this solution but it works.